# How to get LuaSocket udp6 to work for multicast

Tags: lua, udp, ipv6, luasocket

We have just had our game rejected by Apple as we do not support IPv6. We use Codea, a Lua IDE for iPad, which comes with LuaSocket 3.0, and therefore has tcp6() and udp6() extensions.

We cannot get the udp6() broadcast/multicast to work...

On the send side we create a udp6() object, set the timeout to 0, then do a sendto() call with the message, the address and the port...

On the receive side we create a udp6() object, set the option "reuseport", set the socketname to "*" then do a setoption() with "ipv6-add-membership" and {multiaddr="", interface=n}

The problem is we don't know what address to use, we have tried a whole bunch of permutations like FF02::.. and FE80:... but although we get no errors, we get no messages received...

Does anyone have any example code, I'm sure we've missed something fundamental, but we are at a loss...

Codea allows us to export our Lua code for compilation into the app on the MacOS side, but for portability we want to do it all in LuaSocket if possible, rather than using e.g. Bonjour, if that is possible...

Thanks in advance,
Brookesi

Comment: What address to use? It depends. What are you communicating with? Is it a server on the Internet, or devices on the user's LAN?

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton, It is a local multiplayer game on wi-fi, we currently use IPv4 UDP as a broadcast game discovery mechanism between iOS devices, so we send to 255.255.255.255...

Comment: Ah, I don't think you can do that anymore. You may need to switch to IPv6 multicast. This is not going to be a trivial fix.